# Calculating the x, y and z distances between two molecules - AMBER (Molecular Dynamics)

Tags: computational-chemistry, molecular-dynamics

I am interested in calculating the x,y and z distance between two molecules over a given simulation time. I know how to calculate the total (r) distance between them, but I want the distance between them along all three dimensions.

For the total distance, cpptraj can be used as:

```
parm prmtop-file
trajin netcdf-file
distance DIST :1-4@heavy-atoms-from-molecule-1 :5-8@heavy-atoms-from-molecule-2 out dist.out
run
quit
```

But like I said before, I do not want the r-distance. Is there anyway to calculate the x,y and z-distances in cpptraj? If not, what other alternatives do I have?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AMBER, but in LAMMPS there is a file containing all the atom positions and a utility to convert it to a .xyz file which is just a list of all the coordinates. You might try searching for something like an .xyz file?

Comment: I can find the coordinates via a file in AMBER called a .pdb file, but I will have to manually calculate the distances from this, which is over 20000 frames to consider.

I guess I might as well just do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up realizing that if you run:

```
parm prmtop-file
trajin netcdf-file
vector v0 :1-4@heavy-atoms-from-molecule-1 :5-8@heavy-atoms-from-molecule-2 out v0.out magnitude
run
quit
```

You will get the total distance as well as x, y and z distances between your two molecules. The output file will contain 8 columns. The AMBER manual states that they are identified as follows:

**Frame** | x-Vector-Coordinate | **y-Vector-Coordinate** | z-Vector-Coordinate | **x-Origin-Coordinate** | y-Origin-Coordinate | **z-Origin-Coordinate** | Magnitude

The vector coordinates are your x, y and z distances. Magnitude is the total distance.

Decided to share this as someone might run into the same problem one day.